# Chrome messes up SVG files' height while loading pages

Tags: google-chrome, svg, webkit

I'm working with custom SVG files, embedded in `<object>` tags. It renders properly but for some reason, I experience a weird bug on Chrome browser.

On page load, the Chrome seems to "calculate" the height of my elements and displays a wrong height for the wrapping elements. IE and FF behave normally though.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample snippet or fiddle etc, that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, I use an ugly fix. By default, my `<object>` has `height:0` CSS property, then I apply the following script (CoffeeScript syntax):

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('object').each ->
    $(this).load ->
      $(this).css('height', 'auto')
```

It makes the job...